# Undo a custom handsontable action

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I've defined a custom action in the context menu of `handsontable`:

```
function contextMenu(hot){
  var menu = {
      callback: function (key, options) {
        if (key === 'custom') {
          setTimeout(function () {
            myCustomAction(hot);
          }, 100);
        }
      },
      items: {
        "commentsAddEdit": {},
        "commentsRemove": {},
        "hsep1": "---------",
        "remove_row": {},
        "custom" : {
          name: "My custom action"
        },
        "hsep2": "---------",
        "undo": {},
        "redo": {}
      }
    };
  return menu;
}

hot.updateSettings({contextMenu: contextMenu(hot)});
```

I would like to have the possibility to undo this custom action. How to do that, if possible ?

Comment: Have you found a solution for your question?

Comment: @Wlad No, never.